# Importing library in Dart

Tags: import, dart

I know that to import some library, which is located in some folder. Example hiearchy:

```
library1
folder1
    library2
```

Then importing library2 would look like:

```
import 'folder1/library2';
```

But how can I import library1 from library2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import '../library1';
```

or

```dart
import 'my_package:library1.dart';
```

when the file `library1.dart` is stored in `my_package/lib/library1.dart` and your package name in pubspec.yaml is `my_package`.

If the imported file is deeper down the path relative path import is fine, when it's higher up the absolute import path (`package:...`) should be preferred.

Only files stored **somewhere in the the `lib` directory of your package** can be imported using a `package:...` path.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll accept your anwser when it's available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import '../library1.dart';
```